# Jpa with a different param in the object

Tags: java, jpa

i would like know is possible with jpa have something for this.
I would like a generic methode for this :

```
SELECT P FROM personne p WHERE p.fistName = :fistName
SELECT P FROM personne p WHERE p.name = :name
SELECT P FROM personne p WHERE p.name = :name AND p.fistName = :fistName
SELECT P FROM personne p WHERE p.phone = :phone
```

it's possible or i do create all sql query i send a object dans jpa seach the same object .
thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but what you can do is use the [Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm#GJITV) to construct your query programmatically. Then, you could have a generic method to query by a certain property of `Person`:

```
EntityManager em;

public List<Person> queryByPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object value) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
    query.where(cb.equal(person.get(propertyName), value));
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

If you want to query by multiple properties at once, you can use a `Map` like this:

```
public List<Person> queryByPropertyValues(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
    Predicate predicate = cb.and(); // == always true
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : properties.entrySet()) {
        predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(person.get(property.getKey()), property.getValue()));
    }
    query.where(predicate);
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: You're welcome! If you find this answer useful, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it with the big empty tick mark to the left of it.

Comment: how to do this with Criteria    ELECT P FROM personne p WHERE( p.name = :name AND p.fistName = :fistName) OR p.name :name2 .  i would like use ( ) in the sql request